# JQGrid Header "doubling"

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid

I am having a problem with my first jqGrid implementation.  The grid is rendering and loading data.  Paging is working.  However, the grid header is shown twice.  Once as a fixed header.  And also as the first row in the scroll area.  I am using MySql 5.5.11 as the data source, PHP 5.3.6, jQuery 1.6.1., and JqGrid 4.0.0.

The PHP code that backends the grid looks like this:

```
// Processed based on the action.
switch ($lAction)
{
    case "LOAD":

    $page = $_POST['page']; // get the requested page
    $limit = $_POST['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
    $sidx = $_POST['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort
    $sord = $_POST['sord']; // get the direction

    $lDB = new DBConnection();

    $lTable         = "tblWebRequests";
    $lGridColumns   = "id,fname,lname,company,phone,email,reqfor";


    $lGrid = new DBDataGrid($lDB, $lTable, $lGridColumns, 1, 5);

    $response->page     = $page;
    $response->total    = $lGrid->GetTotalPages();
    $response->records  = $lGrid->GetTotalItems();
    $currentPageItems   = $lGrid->GetCurPageItems();

    for($i=0;$i<count($currentPageItems);$i++) 
    {
        $response->rows[$i]['id']=$currentPageItems[$i]['id'];
        $response->rows[$i]['cell']=array(
        $currentPageItems[$i]['id'],
        $currentPageItems[$i]['fname'],
        $currentPageItems[$i]['lname'],
        $currentPageItems[$i]['company'],
        $currentPageItems[$i]['email'],
        $currentPageItems[$i]['phone'],
        $currentPageItems[$i]['reqfor']


        );
    }    

    echo json_encode($response);            

    break;
```

The HTML looks as follows:

```
<!-- Stylesheet includes. -->
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
@import url("css/main.css");    
@import url("css/start/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css");       
@import url("css/ui.jqgrid.css");       
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>;
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>;
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>;

<div class="contentwide">
<div id="databuttons">
<p></p>
<!-- end databuttons  --></div>
<div id="datasection">
    <table id="datatable">

    </table>

<!-- end datasection  --></div>
<p></p><p></p>
<div id="datapager">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#datatable').jqGrid({
            url:'php/DataGridMgr.php',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames:['ID','First','Last','Company','Email','Phone','Request For'],
            colModel:
            [    
                {name:'id',index:'id',width:5,editable:false,hidden:true},     
                {name:'fname',index:'fname', width:20,editable:false,sortable:false},
                {name:'lname',index:'lname', width:20,editable:false,sortable:false},
                {name:'company',index:'company', width:35,editable:false,sortable:false},
                {name:'email',index:'email', width:35,editable:false,sortable:false},
                {name:'phone',index:'phone', width:20,editable:false,sortable:false},
                {name:'reqfor',index:'reqfor', width:25,editable:false,sortable:false}
            ],
            rowNum:5,
            rowList:[],
            imgpath: 'css/start/images', //alters buttons
            pager: $('#datapager'),
            pginput: true,
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            //caption:"Pending Requests",
            width:945,
            height:150,  
            onSelectRow: function(id)
            {
                alert(id);
            }
            //editurl:""
        });



    </script>
<!-- end datapager --></div>
```

I am sure I am missing something simple.  I have searched to no avail for a resolution.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the SQL/PHP is returning the header in the response. Can you make sure the $response is returning correctly?

Comment: I have checked the response and it does not appear to have heading data included? The response does have a page and rows value that is part of JSON i belive. The rest of the response is the actual database data.  Is there anything else I should look for?  Thank you for the help.

Comment: the json response should have page, total, records (count), and then only the data with NO header. It's odd to have the script within the pager div I would move it out and down.  Also should add this line to the javascript: jQuery("#datatable").jqGrid('navGrid','#datapager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});

Comment: Pulling the code out of the pager div seems to have alleviated the heading issue?  But I get a syntax error when I add the jQuery("#datatable").jqGrid('navGrid','#datapager',{edit:false,add:false,del:fal‌se}); line to the existing javascript.  The paging on the grid is not working.  I am sure it has to do with the jQuery("#datatable").jqGrid('navGrid','#datapager',{edit:false,add:false,del:fal‌​se}); statement. But I am not sure what's wrong?  Sorry if I am missing something obvious....I am glad for the help.

Comment: got rid of the syntax error and added the jQuery("#datatable").jqGrid('navGrid','#datapager',{edit:false,add:false,del:fal‌se});  But the paging of the grid is still not working.  I am not sure why?  Any suggestions of things to check?

Comment: Jazaret,                                                             The revised code looks like before with the addition    
jQuery("#datatable").jqGrid('navGrid','#datapager',{add:false, edit:false, del:false});    
 and the code is outside (and below) the page.  As I said before, the headings are no longer doubling, but the paging stopped working.  The page number changes and the record x-y of z changes in the navigator, but the contents of the rows in the grid do not.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The json response should have page, total, records (count), and then only the data with NO header. It's odd to have the script within the pager div I would move it out and down. Also should add this line to the javascript: jQuery("#datatable").jqGrid('navGrid','#datapager',{edit:false,add:false,del:fal‌​se});

Also I don't use PHP/MySQL (I use asp.net) but it looks like you're hardcoding the page values?

$lGrid = new DBDataGrid($lDB, $lTable, $lGridColumns, 1, 5);

Comment: You are correct, 1 is the page of the grid to retrieve, and 5 in the number of rows per page.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I had apparently had an oh darn you did exactly what I told you moment....After replacing the page and rows per page values that were hard coded with the correct variables, it works.  Thanks for pointing this out.